# Install ADT plugin in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I want to install ADT plugin in Eclipse with Zip file but when i click on next button in first page of install, the progress late long time. I wait around 3hours that i wait for install but now half ADT install :(

In install window, above of progress bar, writes: cannot perform operation.Computing alternate solutions, may take a while: 7/15 .

Why to install ADT needs a long time? Is this no problem or install has a problem?

sorry for my poor english and Thanks for help

Comment: It still needs internet connections coz download some files it must have fast internet connection

Comment: But when i use ADT Plugin in zip file, i don't need to use internet. Is this incorrect?

Comment: no u still need internet i did the same and thinking same but it downloaded some file instead\

Comment: but i think, i don't need to use internet, around 3 months ago, i install this without filter breaker and this install without internet.May this long time be for my computer? I mean maybe my computer is low level technology!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even when you are installing ADT using zipped file, You need internet connection to complete installation.

If the site is blocked, the only way is to copy-paste the eclipse folder from your friend's system, who are using the same platform and already installed ADT plugin.

One more step: Make sure the SDK location is correct.

Window -> Preferences -> Android. Here, make sure you use the correct SDK Location.

Comment: Thanks. I have internet but i can't access to this site. a question: if i need to internet, what i have progress to install?

Comment: Seems like zipped ADT does not contain all the files needed. After installing a half, it fetches files from the site. That's why it stuck in the middle as the site is not accessible.

Comment: Thanks. finally i can install ADT but when i want to run a program, the program has error, Unknown error: Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder! WHY?

Comment: Check the SDK Location

Comment: SDK location is true but i think SDK version is 20 and ADT version is 22. I think, i should to up to date SDK version :(

Comment: oh that may cause problem. Are you using Linux? dx.jar is located at AndroidSDK->Platform-Tools->lib.

Comment: I use windows xp(32bit). dx.jar is in lib folder but Eclipse can not find that:( Do you think, this problem is for difference version of ADT and SDK?

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you use the normal mode to install it?

1. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
2. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
3. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
4. Click OK and go on :)

All the instruction can be found in the guide [Installing the Eclipse Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.I can't use this site because this site is filter for my country :( this is single way for me :( Have you any solutions?

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using? Check about compability between them

Comment: I install ADT 20.0 version and i install Eclipse IDE for java developers(http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-java-kepler-R-win32.zip) Is this problem? Should ADT and Eclipse have same version? I force to use ADT 20.0 because i have SDK version 20.0 and now i can't get newer SDK version :(

Comment: @SensorS Download kepler and ADT 22 and Android 4.3 use latest version

Comment: yeah, i download kepler version of Eclipse and ADT 22 but my SDK version is 20.