# how to install adt plugins in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt

I have downloaded eclipse(Kepler) where I couldn't find the option to create the android project in file-new option of eclipse.how can I get Adt plugin into the eclipse to create android project

Comment: This is available too in the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Comment: Hope this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588886/install-adt-plugin-in-eclipse

Comment: Now its done...I was doing a mistake .choose windows-customized perspective-menu visibility-file-new.Now select android Application project and android xml. click ok. Its done