# Eclipse->Import->No *Android* here

Tags: android, eclipse, import, missing-features

I am trying to import an android project in Eclipse but when I go to File->Import->** Android ** there is no Android tab. Further I should click on Android->Existing Android Code.
Why don't I have an Android tab in Import?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you do not have the ADT plugin installed. Note that Eclipse support by Google has ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install the plugin for android in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You need **ADT** plugin.

[Install ADT plugin in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588886/install-adt-plugin-in-eclipse)

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/android-adt-extentions

Also check this:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html

> Important: Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse
>   has ended, per our announcement. You should migrate your app
>   development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible..

Answer (score 0):

You should use Android Studio instead of Eclipse. Googe no longer supports Eclipse as a supported IDE for Android, and they suggest switching to Android Studio.