# Android SDK Manager is not displaying in Eclipse list

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I have installed 
- Android SDK Manager, 
- Android Virtual Device Manager

but in my eclipse -> Windows[ I am not getting SDK Manager options ] is there any settings to enable it.

please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

First, please notice that:

> Important: Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse
>   has ended, per our announcement. You should migrate your app
>   development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible. For more
>   information on transitioning to Android Studio, see Migrating from
>   Eclipse ADT.

Read whole article here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html

or find more information here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html

If you still want to develop in Eclipse, here you would find how to integrate it with Eclipse: [Install ADT plugin in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588886/install-adt-plugin-in-eclipse)

Hope it help